# Dynamically change project stage value at runtime using JNDI

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, jndi, websphere-8

I need to change the value of the project stage dynamically ( at runtime ), based on the environment, using JNDI. From what I understand, the JNDI will override what is defined in web.xml.  Is there a document / link that will help me with how I should code it? I am using websphere 8.5

In some examples I have seen that it is defined as resource-ref, but I am not sure I understand how is that used with JNDI to make it work and change the value at runtime.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is 'project stage'? What exact piece of configuration do you want to manage through JNDI?

Comment: [This link](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_new_feature2) explains project stage much better than I can attempt to.  I want to make sure that in production, it will be "Production". When using the web.xml context-param, many applications are getting moved with the value of "Development".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JSF 2.0 spec states, you can override context parameter `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` via JNDI entry, which is looked via reference `java:comp/env/jsf/ProjectStage`.

To override the context parameter, you need to define following resource environment reference in your web.xml file:

```
<resource-env-ref>
   <description />
   <resource-env-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</resource-env-ref-name>
   <resource-env-ref-type>java.lang.String</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

in the application server configuration, you can define your ProjectStage value via Namespace binding ( in the web admin console select `Environment > Name Space Bindings`,  define new String variable with jndi name `jsf/ProjectStage` and value `Development` or `Production`, depending on the environment).

Finally you need to bind your reference in the project with variable in JNDI. You can do it it 2 ways, via `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file, defining:

```
<resource-ref name="jsf/ProjectStage" binding-name="jsf/ProjectStage" />
```

Or during application installation, in the step were you provide mappings for Resource environment references.

For detailed discussion on this topic check [Dynamically change project stage value at runtime using JNDI](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=556839ae-9264-4f8e-9af8-d3dba5f605ff)

Comment: Thank you, Gas.  I am the same person who asked that question on dW because I didn't get an answer here. :) 

I really appreciate the help you and Brian provided me in getting this resolved and I also now understand the difference between resource-ref and resource-env-ref.

Comment: You're welcome. I suspected that :-). I just created brief version here, so others could find it easier also.

Comment: Thank you.  It was good that you answered it, so there is a description here.  I was just going to add the link to dW post so that others would find it.  But now, they have the answer right here as well.